Forgetful functor $V: \underline{\mathbf{PSet}} \rightarrow \underline{\mathbf{Set}}$ is not full
This might be a trivial question, but I don't understand why the trivial functor $V: \underline{\mathbf{PSet}} \rightarrow \underline{\mathbf{Set}}$ is not full. ($\underline{\mathbf{PSet}}$ is the category of pointed sets.)
In my mind, for any $g: X \rightarrow Y$, I can just pick out any $x \in X$ and then fix $y := g(x) \in Y.$ If I then define $f: (X, x) \rightarrow (Y, y)$, I should get $V(f) = g.$ I tried playing around with the empty set $\varnothing$, but $\varnothing$ is not even an object of $\underline{\mathbf{PSet}}$, if I understand correctly.
Evidently, there is something wrong about my argumentation, but I can't figure out what exactly. Help is appreciated!

If $X=(Y={1,2},1),$ then every map $X\to X$ is sends $1\mapsto 1,$ so this doesn't include all functions $Y\to Y.$

By definition, a functor $F\colon\mathcal{C}\to\mathcal{D}$ is full if, for any $x,y\in\mathcal{C}$ the induced map $\mathcal{C}(x,y)\to\mathcal{D}(Fx,Fy), f\mapsto Ff$ is surjective. Your argumentation does not really relate to what you would have to show if you want to prove that $V$ is full.
Let's first see why $V$ is not full. This would be the statement that, for any given pointed sets $(X,x)$ and $(Y,y)$, the map $\mathbf{PSet}((X,x),(Y,y))\to\mathbf{Set}(X,Y), f \mapsto f$ is surjective. This is not true: for most sets, there are strictly more functions that just those that preserve some basepoints that were fixed in advance. In your argument, you allow yourself to pick the basepoints afterwards, which is why it does not relate to fullness of $V$.

Yes, you are completely right, I forgot that $x$ and $y$ have to be fixed beforehand... Dumb oversight on my part, thank you very much!

$V$ being full means that for every two objects $(X, x_0), (Y, y_0)$ of $\mathrm{PSet}$ the map $\operatorname{Hom}_{\mathrm{PSet}}((X, x_0), (Y, y_0)) \to \operatorname{Hom}_{\mathrm{Set}}(X, Y)$ given by applying $V$ to morphisms is surjective, and here $x_0$ and $y_0$ are fixed; this map is clearly not surjective in general since it doesn't hit functions not mapping $x_0$ to $y_0$.
It is true that you can always change $x_0$ and $y_0$ to fit your needs, but then you're talking about different objects in $\mathrm{PSet}$ and therefore a different Hom-set.

Suppose $(X,x),(Y,y)$ are pointed sets and $f:X\to Y$ is any function such that $f(x)\neq y$, then $f$ is not in the image of the morphism
$$ {\rm Hom}_{\underline{\mathbf{PSet}}}((X,x),(Y,y))\to {\rm Hom}_{\underline{\mathbf{Set}}}(X,Y) $$
so the functor $V$ is not full.
